# Simplify logic function

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I am having a hard time simplifying this logic function:

\$ f = \overline{x_3}\cdot\overline{x_4} + \overline{x_1}\cdot\overline{x_3}+\overline{x_2}\cdot\overline{x_3}+\overline{x_1}\cdot\overline{x_4}+\overline{x_1}\cdot\overline{x_2}+\overline{x_2}\cdot\overline{x_4}\$

I found out on wolfram that it simplifies to :

\$ f = \overline{((x_1(x_2(x_3+x_4))+x_3\cdot x_4))+x_2\cdot x_3\cdot x_4)}\$

but no matter what I tried I cannot get to this result.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That doesn't look "simplified".

Comment: You said "no matter what I tried"... We need you to show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wolfram alpha simplification really simplifies nothing (and all it does was inelegantly apply de Morgan's rules, which you **really** should be aware of, anyway).

As this is  homework, only a hint: Consider \$a=\overline{x_1}, b=\overline{x_2}, c=\overline{x_3}, d=\overline{x_4}\$. Great, now you have four different things that you combine (with \$\cdot\$).

How many different 2-sets can you make out of four different inputs? What does that tell you about your \$f\$?